# Button adding user input to the array. Then typing out the data in array to a <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to coding so please ignore any unwritten rules I might be missing.
Any feedback is appreciated.

Basically, I have three text inputs, Name:, Age:, and Password:
If not all fields are filled and error message will occur, but if everything is filled in and the user presses the button I need the information to be saved to an array, and for the information (only Name: & Age:) to be typed out below, along with two other "personas" that are to be added via (Push) method.

However, I'm not getting these different stages to work together. I am receiving different errors each time I change something. As previously stated I am a novice within coding and will take any help I can get.

```js
function buttonclick() {
  validate();
  addToArray();
}

function validate() {
  var name = document.getElementById("NameInput");
  var age = document.getElementById("AgeInput");
  var password = document.getElementById("PasswordInput");
  if (name.value == "" || password.value == "" || age.value == "") {
    alert("Field is required");
    return false;
  } else {
    true;
  }
  if (password.value == "IHM") {
    true;
  } else {
    alert("Not a valid password")
    return false;
  }
}

function addToArray() {
  let persons = [];
  let person1 = {
    Uname: "Marcus",
    Uage: 34
  }
  let person2 = {
    Uname: "Cihan",
    Uage: 35
  }
  // Gets name from the input
  let Uname = document.getElementById("NameInput").value;
  // Gets age from the input
  let Uage = document.getElementById("AgeInput").value;
  // Adds antoher name to the array?
  persons.push(person1, person2);
  // Sorts the array 
  persons.sort();

  /* Is this needed?
      const write = () => {
          NameInput.forEach()
          AgeInput.forEach()
      }*
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="NameInput">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Age" id="AgeInput">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="PasswordInput">
</div>
<button onclick="buttonclick()" type="button">Submit</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Please correct the errors currently thrown when running your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code in the vsCode, and your array gets the two objects if you check in the console, I add an object of user name and age- from inputs. I hope that im understand.. that my code:

```
enter code here   function buttonclick() {
    validate(addToArray);
}

var uname = document.getElementById("NameInput");
var age = document.getElementById("AgeInput");

function validate(cb) {
    var password = document.getElementById("PasswordInput");
    if (name.value == "" || password.value == "" || age.value == "") {
        alert("Field is required");
        return false;
    } else {
        true;
    }
    if (password.value == "IHM") {
        true;
    } else {
        alert("Not a valid password")
        return false;
    }
    cb();
}

function addToArray() {
    let persons = [];
    let person1 = {
        Uname: "Marcus",
        Uage: 34
    }
    let person2 = {
        Uname: "Cihan",
        Uage: 35
    }
    // Gets name from the input
    let objOfUserInputs = {};
    objOfUserInputs.uname = uname.value;
    objOfUserInputs.uage = age.value;
    // Gets age from the input
    let Uage = document.getElementById("AgeInput").value;
    // Adds antoher name to the array?
    persons.push(person1, person2, objOfUserInputs);
    // Sorts the array
    persons.sort();
    console.log(persons);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: You don't need to write true in the conditionals, you could just return if you don't need to check the returned value

eg.:

For the first conditional, you don't even need the else part

```
    if (name.value == "" || password.value == "" || age.value == "") {
        alert("Field is required");
        return
    }
```

For the second conditional

```
    if (password.value == "IHM"){
        return true
    } else {
        alert ('Wrong password')
    }
```

You could even write it like this, since if the condition is met, the function will return and the alert won't trigger

```
    if (password.value == "IHM"){
        return true
    }
    alert ('Wrong password')
```

Try it out.

Then you want to append those values to the array (if i understood correctly) and you want them to be displayed, alongside with the others.
I suggest you create a similar object and then push that object to the array, then you can sort it
So, create the object from the user input:

```
    let Uname = document.getElementById("NameInput").value;
    let Uage = parseInt(document.getElementById("AgeInput").value);
    //You need to use parseInt() if you want that item to be an integer
    let person3 = {
        Uname: Uname,
        Uage: Uage 
    }
```

And then push every object to the array

```
    persons.push(person1, person2, person3);
    //return the array
    return persons
```

to sort the array, by name i imagine, just using sort would not suffice, as you want to sort on the 'name' property, so you have to pass a function to sort that orders the items by their name.
You can check it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
    persons.sort(function (a, b) {
        var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
        }

        // names must be equal
        return 0;
    });
```

The last step, if i understand correctly, is placing all the items, in the ordered array, inside the output div, so let's keep the write() function.
You have to iterate through each element, and then you need to insert the HTML that you have created inside the 'output' div.
There are a few ways to to this, you can create elements in the js, or you can append the HTML directly to the div.
Let's say you want to place them in an unordered list.

```
    //pass the result from the addToArray() funtion to the write() function
    function write(persons){
        let output = document.getElementById('output')
        //clean output div otherwise everytime it will append new content
        output.innerHTML = ""
        let ul = document.createElement('ul')
        //Iterate
        for( let i of persons){
            let li = document.createElement('li')
            li.innerHTML = `${i.Uname} - ${i.Uage}`
            ul.appendChild(li)
        }
        output.appendChild(ul)
    }
```

and finally the onclick function, you need to make sure that everything is as you want before adding it to the output div, so check if the verify function has returned true(or whatever you prefer), and the create the array and write it to the div

```
    function buttonclick() {
        if (validate() === true){
            write(addToArray())
        }
    }
```

here is it in full

```
    <body>

        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="NameInput">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Age" id="AgeInput">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="PasswordInput">
        </div>
        <button onclick="buttonclick()" type ="button">Submit</button>


    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        function buttonclick() {
            if (validate() === true){
                write(addToArray())
            }
        }

        function validate() {
            var name = document.getElementById("NameInput");
            var age = document.getElementById("AgeInput");
            var password = document.getElementById("PasswordInput");

            if (name.value == "" || password.value == "" || age.value == "") {
                alert("Field is required");
                return
            }

            if (password.value == "IHM") { 
                return true
            }
            alert("Not a valid password")
        }

        function addToArray() {
            let persons = [];

            let person1 = {
                    Uname: "Marcus",
                    Uage: 34
                }
            let person2 = {
                    Uname: "Cihan",
                    Uage: 35
                }
            // Gets name from the input
            let Uname = document.getElementById("NameInput").value;
            // Gets age from the input
            let Uage = parseInt(document.getElementById("AgeInput").value);
            //Create the object
            let person3 = {
                Uname: Uname,
                Uage: Uage

            }
            // Adds antoher name to the array?
            persons.push(person1, person2, person3);
            // Sorts the array 
            persons.sort(function (a, b) {
                var nameA = a.Uname.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
                var nameB = b.Uname.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
                if (nameA < nameB) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (nameA > nameB) {
                    return 1;
                }
                // names must be equal
                return 0;
            });
            return persons
        }
        function write(persons) {
            let output = document.getElementById('output')
            //clean output div otherwise everytime it will append new content
            output.innerHTML = ""
            let ul = document.createElement('ul')
            //Iterate
            for (let i of persons) {
                let li = document.createElement('li')
                li.innerHTML = `${i.Uname} - ${i.Uage}`
                //Append items to ul
                ul.appendChild(li)
            }
            //Append ul to the 'output' div
            output.appendChild(ul)
        }
        </script>
    </body>
```

There are many ways you can accomplish this, i have tried to stay as close as possible to your example so you can understand better, i hope it'll help you, have a good day.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have changed my code together with a classmate to an alternative method. But this was really explanatory and cleared things up for me.